# Measuring longitudinal modes of a laser with a scanning Fabry-Perot spectrometer

Tags: optics, laser, interference

Given a laser operating at a wavelength $\lambda = 1.084 \mu m$ on two longitudinal modes $300 MHz$ apart, I have to find the minimum free spectral range $FSR_m$ necessary to correctly measure the two modes. I've chosen to use a free spectral range $FSR >2B$ where $B$ is the bandwidth of the intensity spectrum to measure, so $B = 300 MHz$. With my choice, $FSR_m = 600 MHz$. $FSR_m$ can also be expressed as a function of the distance $d$ between the two  parallel mirrors of the interfometer. By calculating the distance $d$, I get:

$FSR = \frac{c}{2d} > FSR_m$ where $c$ is the velocity of light in vacuum

So, $d < \frac{c}{2FSR_m} = 25 cm$

Ideally, this condition should allow me to measure the intensity of one frequency ( one mode ) at a time ( assuming that the transmission function of the interferometer has very narrow peaks ) because the transmission maxima are certainly more distant than the whole bandwidth of the intensity spectrum. How is this done? By keeping the distance $d$ below the maximum allowed distance of $25cm$, the positions of the frequencies for which I have a transmission maximum increase.

For example, if I use the maximum allowed distance of $d= 25 cm$, the frequency maxima of the transmission of the FP interferometer are $f_m = m*600 MHz$.

How can I ensure to have two maxima at the correct frequencies of the longitudinal modes, so I can measure their intensity? Couldn't it happen that I get the first transmission maximum already beyond the longitudinal modes?

Comment: Is this an experimental or theoretical problem? That is, is this something you're really trying to do in the lab? Also, can you explain more clearly what your goal is? You say you want to "correctly measure the two modes". What do you mean by this? What about the two modes do you want to measure? Frequency difference between them? Absolute frequency in each? Relative power in each? Absolute power in each?

Comment: This is a theoretical problem that was asked in my optics course during one of the exams in the previous years. My goal is to find the minimum free spectral range to correctly distinguish the two modes, spaced by a frequency difference of 300 MHz. I don't know anything about the relative power/absolute power or absolute frequency of each mode. After finding the minimum free spectral range, how does the scan work to actually make a measurement?

Comment: I am also confused about what this question is asking. The question implies you have already chosen FSR = 600 MHz, but your comment says "My goal is to find the minimum free spectral range to correctly distinguish the two modes, spaced by a frequency difference of 300 MHz".  Your last paragraph suggests you want to measure the intensity of the modes. What do you mean by "ensure to have two maxima at the correct frequencies of the longitudinal modes"? If the FSR is large enough, you don't have to "ensure" anything - the spectrum will have repeating pairs of 300 MHz peaks spaced by the FSR.

Comment: But how can the spacing between maxima be fixed If I have to vary the distance when scanning the spectrum?

Comment: The FSR changes as you scan, but the fractional change in FSR between maxima is tiny, $\sim \lambda/d$.  I suggest looking at something like the the relevant articles from [Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/fabry.html) and [Thorlabs](https://www.thorlabs.com/NewGroupPage9_PF.cfm?ObjectGroup_ID=859) (especially figures 4 & 5).

Comment: I've read the articles but I can't seem to find an answer to my question. I understand that FSR must be greater than the spectrum bandwidth, but let's consider again the two laser modes spaced by 300 MHz. The laser emits two frequencies: $f_1$ and $f_2$ with $f_2 - f_1 = 300 MHz$. The transmitted maxima are a function of distance: the maximum of order m for the frequencies $f_1$ and $f_2$ is obtained if $d = m*\frac{c}{2f1}$ or $d=m*\frac{c}{2f2}$. What guarantees me that these values are inside the range of distances allowed to have FSR greater than bandwidth?

Comment: FSR=c/2d, so to get FSR > bandwidth, choosing $d$ such that c/2d > bandwidth will guarantee that FSR > bandwidth.  This is trivial, so clearly your question must be about something else, but it is not obvious what.
Are you asking if there is a lower bound on $d$? To observe maxima from both modes, then $d$ must be greater than the larger of the two half-wavelengths $\lambda_1/2=c/2f_1$ and $\lambda_2/2=c/2f_2$, so that the $m=1$ maxima for both modes can be observed.  Normal FP spectrometers operate over mm or cm distances, so never come close to this lower bound for 1.084 µm radiation.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I wanted to ask. Sorry if I have not been clear before and thanks for your answer

Comment: Happy to help. I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowed range for d is
$$\frac{\mathrm{Max}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)}{2} < d < \frac{c}{2B}$$

The requirement that FSR > bandwidth sets the upper bound on from FSR=c/2d, i.e. d < c/2B (where B is bandwidth).

The lower bound on d comes from the requirement that to observe maxima from both modes, d must be greater than the larger of the two half-wavelengths $\lambda_1/2=d/2f_1$ and $\lambda_2/2=d/2f_2$, so that the m=1 maxima for both modes can be observed. Normal FP spectrometers operate over mm or cm distances, so never come close to this lower bound for 1.084 µm radiation. [Fibre optic Fabry-Perot cavities as short as 2.8 µm](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.snb.2017.01.081) have been fabricated, however, which is getting close to this limit.